# Bash Script to generate HTML Template

Tags: bash

I want a Bash script that generates a HTML template. The template will include libraries based on the input arguments at the command line. Here is my idea:

```
#!/bin/bash

function libraries
{
  if [ "$1" == "bootstrap" ]; then
      echo "<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />"
  fi
}

##### Main

cat << _EOF_
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title> </title>
      $(libraries)
  </head>

  <body>

  </body>
  </html>
_EOF_
```

When I run `./template_creator.sh bootstrap` I get this output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title> </title>

  </head>

  <body>

  </body>
  </html>
```

If I don't include the if statement and just echo, it outputs fine. So I am thinking the trouble is in the if statement. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a function, `$1` refers to the first argument passed *to that function*, not the first argument passed to the script. You can either pass the script's first argument on to the function by using `$(libraries "$1")` in the here-document, or assign it to a global variable at the beginning of the script and then use that in the function.

Comment: Could I accommodate multiple arguments using this method?

Comment: @iCodeYouCodeWeAllCode: Sure, but there's lots of opportunity for confusion if you aren't careful. For instance, if you used `$(somefunc "$2" "heading" "$1")`, then inside the function `$1` will refer to the script's second argument, and `$3` will refer to its first. If this makes sense in terms of what the function does, great! But if it'd be clearer to have consistent references throughout, globals are a better way to go. You can also mix approaches based on what's clearest in each situation.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `printf` to inject variables in your template.

In your template use the `printf` formats (eg. `%s`) as inserting points.

This way you can even use a file for your template (calling it with `tpl=$(cat "main.tpl"`) and handle your variables in your script.

```
libraries() {
  if [ "$1" == "bootstrap" ]; then
      link='<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" />'
      printf "$tpl" "$link"
  fi
}

##### Main

read -d '' tpl << _EOF_
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title> </title>
      %s
  </head>

  <body>

  </body>
  </html>
_EOF_

libraries "$1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `$(libraries)` write `$(libraries) $1`.

Comment: Change made. Ran ./template_creator.sh bootstrap. But it shows 'bootstrap' below <title></title>.